# Java libgdx(desktop/android) multiplayer game how to

Tags: java, tcp, udp, libgdx, multiplayer

I have a game called wizard wars that I have been working on.  This game needs to allow 2 players to play at one time, and would need a TCP connection to communicate spell creation/destruction ect., and a UDP connection to handle locations ect.  It would have a client and a host side.  That being said my program is designed to run on Android.  All of the tutorials/information I have found online has been for JApplets or something like that.  So what I would like is some help with ever short code examples of how to set up/use connections, or just a link to some sufficiently helpfull information on how to set up the actual connections.

Comment: Have you looked at LibGDX with KryoNet?

Comment: Not yet, but ill look into it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best approach (or at least 1 approach) would be to use normal HTTP requests : http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Net.html

You create a webservice implementing REST and create calls for both updating and consuming data.

Alternatively, if you're just going to use Android and Desktop you may also use WebSockets : https://github.com/pepedeab/libGDX-Net

Comment: Can WebSockets not be used with html5?

Answer (score 4):

**For those who don't read comments, but still looking for tcp client.**

You can use KryoNet which supports Desktop and Android
https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryonet

Answer (score 2):

Have you guys looked at the [multiplayer super jumper tutorial](http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=12566)? Its written using AppWarp and is being actively used in the libgdx community as well.

Comment: Thx dude! This seems to be exactly what I am looking for!